# go-cas 302 loop as Middleware

Tags: go, cas

I am trying to develop an app that offers multiple ways to authenticate users. The first version only supported WPA, and now I need to add CAS. In the main section of my app, I set which authProvider I want to use. However, I'm facing a 302 loop when I try to authenticate with CAS. It seems the CAS client isn't being associated with the HTTP request.

Usually, I associate the CAS Client with http.Server.Handler, and it works perfectly. Below is how I've tried to declare my middleware:

```
    o := om{
        authProvider: auth.NewCASAuthProvider("https://cas.domain.tld/cas"),
    }

    http.Handle("/", o.authProvider.Middleware(http.Handler(o.authProvider)))
```

And my implemtantion:

```
func (c *CASAuthProvider) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Hello from MyHandler!"))
}

func (c *CASAuthProvider) Middleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return c.Client.Handler(next)
}
func NewCASAuthProvider(u string) *CASAuthProvider {
    uri, err := url.Parse(u)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%s", err)

    }
    return &CASAuthProvider{
        Client: cas.NewClient(&cas.Options{
            URL: uri,                                   
        }),                                   
    }
}
```

From what I understand from the go-cas documentation, I should only need to call c.Client.Handler, as that function calls setClient which binds the CAS request context to the current HTTP request. However, I must be doing something wrong, given the loop issue I'm facing.

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

After being blocked for entire day, obviously I did find out just after asking for some help! I change `Client.Handler` for `Client.Handle`:

Implementation:

```
func (c *CASAuthProvider) Middleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return c.Client.Handle(next)
}
```

main.go:

```
http.Handle("/", o.authProvider.Middleware(http.HandlerFunc(o.indexHandler)))

func (o *om) indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if !cas.IsAuthenticated(r) {
        cas.RedirectToLogin(w, r)
        return
    }
    log.Printf("hello %s", cas.Username(r))
    w.Write([]byte("welcome"))
}
```